# wpflocalizeextension refer to a .resx file in another project

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization

I am trying to centralise my localisation in a multi project solution.
A decision was made to use the extension which works well in the code behind, but not in the xaml. The .resx file was working sitting in the local project properties directory

```
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="Project1"

lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

But I can't seem to get it to consume the propeties in a different project
for example

```
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="clr-namespace:Localisation;assembly=Localisation.Properties"

 lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

and iterations of the same, is this possible?

Comment: What is the `ResxLocalizationProvider`, can you share the code?

Comment: They are required parameters for the package wpflocalizeextension.

Comment: https://github.com/XAMLMarkupExtensions/WPFLocalizationExtension/wiki/Preparing-the-XAML-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the solution was to create linked files to the other project's resx files rather than a direct reference from within the xaml bit clunky but a solution.